# pythonic way to check multiple boolean operators in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-operations

I'm sure there is a way to simplify this if statement but I don't remember it and after googling for a while I couldn't find it. Any ideas?

```py
if user_input.lower() == 'yes' or user_input.lower() == 'y':
    print('Done!')
```

Comment: Using a `tuple` with the `in` operator will give you a slightly better performance than a `list` or a `set`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether a value is present in an iterable using the `in` keyword: `user_input.lower() in ("yes", "y")` will evaluate to `True` if the input is either `'yes'` or `'y'`.

Alternatively, for more complex checks, you might consider `any()`, which takes an iterable of boolean statements and returns `True` if any of them are `True`. For example, the statement `any([user_input.lower() in ("yes", "y"), skip_check, ignore_input])`, where `skip_check` and `ignore_input` are some other boolean flags you might care about, will be `True` if any of those things are true.

`all()` is similar to `any()` but, as the name suggests, requires that all elements be true in order to come out `True`. You can think of `any()` as being analogous to a chained `or` statement, while `all()` would be like replacing those `or`s with `and`.